# Responsive Tumblr video embeds (for text posts)

Tags: css, youtube, embed, tumblr, tumblr-themes

I'm using the following solution to make Tumblr embeds YouTube video via the video post type responsive:

```
.video-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56,25%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 0 !important;
}

.video-wrapper iframe {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Along with this JS snippet

```
    // get all video wrappers
    var videoWrappers = document.getElementsByClassName('video-wrapper');
    // loop over each of them
    [].forEach.call( videoWrappers, function (el, i) {
        // cache width and height values of the iframe
        var width = el.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].width,
            height = el.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].height;
        // apply the padding to the video wrapper
        el.style.paddingBottom = height / width * 100 + '%';
    });
```

This is working fine when the post type is video - however, when a video is embed within a standard text post the video is no longer responsive (see [blog.paulyb.me](http://blog.paulyb.me) to see this in action).

I'm trying to figure out how to adapt the code to fix this, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this problem because most probably your HTML for Video posts are something like;

```
{block:Video}

<div class="video-wrapper">
{VideoEmbed-700}
</div>

{/block:Video}
```

And this only affects the Video posts.

The fix; 
You can not have a `DIV` just around the inline video in the body of a Text post in your HTML, but you can have one around the Text post body, like;

```
{block:Text}

{block:Title} <div class="text_title"> {Title} </div> {/block:Title}
<div class="text_body">
{Body}
</div>

{/block:Text}
```

Now you can use your script to also get the specific `iframe`s inside `.text_body`.

Notes:

Now you can use `querySelectorAll` instead, and get the `iframe`s like; `document.querySelctorAll(".video-wrapper iframe, .text_body iframe#youtube_iframe")`.

Optionally you can try using the unit `vw` for your layout, makes it easy to handle things like this with just CSS. For example you videos are `50vw` in `width`, then you can set the video's `height` to `28.125vw` for 16:9 ratio.

**Update:**

You could not make it work and you did not post the codes you tried so I can not actually answer why, but your script should look something like (I am setting the `height` instead so you will not have to do a lot of work in you CSS):

```
var wrap = document.querySelctorAll(".video-wrapper iframe, .text_body iframe#youtube_iframe"), i;

for (i = 0; i < wrap.length; i += 1) {
    wrap[i].style.height = wrap[i].clientWidth * 0.5625 + 'px';
}
```

When you try this, do not forget to change the CSS that you have in question, you will not need most of it.

Try! and let me know!

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I can not get this solution to work. I have added a div to the body of the text post and duplicated the two classes and named text_body and text_body iframe. I've then updated the js with your line of code (I tried document.querySelctorAll and document.querySelectorAll in case yours is a typo?). This causes both video types to stop displaying at all. I have alternatively tried just applying the css and js to the text body, leaving the standard video post with no styling, and this still causes the text body video to stop displaying.

Comment: UPDATE: I experimented with just giving the text body the same video-wrapper class and this made the video perfectly responsive like the video post type. However, this also made all text from the text post types disappear. So, not sure if there is potential solution here?

Comment: About your update: That is probably because you have styles set for ".video-wrapper".

Comment: Is the css required to make this solution responsive? I have used the code exactly as you have posted, with all but essential html removed from the template, and the videos only display at a fixed size.

Comment: You are talking about when you resize the window after the page is loaded? No, not most of it, and the code I wrote in the answer is what you have to replace your code in question with (for example). You will still have put the codes in a function and call it again when you resize the browser window. like: `window.addEventListener('resize', theFunctionYouMade);` or however you were already doing it. I can only answer what you have in question.

Answer (score 0):

I got close with the above suggestions getting a responsive iframe in place for the video in the text post, however the video itself was not smoothly resizing with the frame. After much playing around, I came across fitvids.js which does exactly what I require.

[fitvids.js](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitVids.js)